# Is it possible to add icon on the iOS widget titlebar right?

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

As title, is possible add any icon or customize style(eg. mail icon ...) on the iOS widget title bar

Or any idea to get widget title bar instance?

THX!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which icon should be displayed in the title bar.

By default, iOS displays a scaled-down version of your app icon, but you can provide a custom icon. The [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/) advise against the use of custom icons, though:

> All icons should clearly identify your app—ideally, they should match your app icon.

I don't think that it is (and should be) possible to customize the title bar in other ways.